# JSON response data size issue

Tags: json, google-api, google-analytics-api, callout

I am using [Discover the Google Analytics platform](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com) to generate queries in order to make callouts to GA from inside a SalesForce application. Upon creating the custom the report an API Query URI is generated which presents the  data from the report in a JSON format.

One example uri looks like the following:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=[my gi id] &start-date=[start date]&end-date=[end date[&metrics=ga%3Asessions%2Cga%3AsessionDuration&dimensions=ga%3AdaysSinceLastSession%2Cga%3Acampaign%2Cga%3AsourceMedium%2Cga%3AsocialNetwork%2Cga%3Adimension2&filters=ga%3AsessionDuration%3E1&access_token=[my access token]
```

The issue is that the presented data is limited to 1000 rows max, and I am not sure how can I surpass this size view limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google analytics API has a field you can send called [max-results](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#maxResults)  if you add

```
&max-results=10000
```

to your request you will get paging of 10000 rows. That is the max you can set it to if there are more results a nextlink will be returned with the results that you can use to make more requests to get the additional data.

Comment: thanks you for your answer. This was exactly what I was looking for. So the next link would be provided in the json response?

Comment: yup if there are more rows you will get a nextlink in the json response  send maxrows of 100 and test it if you like.